# CRON Expression for Off-business / night hours

Tags: cron

So I am using Apache Nifi CRON expression and I wanted a processor to run every-single-second between 6pm and 7 AM at night time.

This is what I came up with:

```
* * 18-7 ? * * *
```

What I was looking for was that it would STOP the processor at 7 AM. It would START the processor at 6 PM and work every second, not just work once per hour.

Thereby working nifi in the off-business hours.

However, what I noticed at 7:30 AM is that it was STILL running, which makes no sense to me. Or is it inclusive?? as in, it runs every second at "7" as well? 7:00 to 7:59 ? Maybe I should try 18-6?

Comment: You need two separate `cron` jobs: `* * 18-23 * * *` and `* * 0-7 * * *`

Comment: Hmm, but how would I do that? I don't think I can separate or have two cron jobs. Only one expression is allowed. What about? `* * 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,18,19,20,21,22,23 ? * * *`

Comment: You can have multiple cron jobs using normal unix cron. I don't know about Apache Nifi (I never heard of it before today).

Comment: Also as a side note: what the heck is the `?` for? I don't get it. You didn't use it but my cron-generator uses it for some reason.

Comment: [Cron expression for a time range](//stackoverflow.com/q/3282036)

Comment: I think I can have different processors with different cron jobs (a processor is like running a jar). However, in my case I only have one processor. So I need one cron expression. Otherwise, I'm not sure how else I can accomplish this. There may be other creative ideas here.

Comment: Also what about just running the CRON manually for 14 hours? Say you start it 5 pm manually, then it runs for 14 hours that's 7 AM right ?

Comment: Cron specifies START times, the second time is not the "end" time, it is in fact the last Start time. Most of the examples above specify multiple hourly start times. (depending on the implementation of CRON the third element could be Hour or DayOfMonth-- we really need to know which implementation).  CRON does not specify an END time, end occurs when the process finishes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a comma to indicate multiple ranges:
`* * 18-23,0-7 * * *`.

Also note that most cron processors use UTC time.